# Can't make Python script run anywhere on Linux machine through setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to make a python script executable anywhere in any computer that installs my library, but I can't make it work. Here is my project tree:

```
├── pysdf
│   ├── conversions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── naming.py
│   ├── parse.py
│   ├── parse.pyc
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── sdf2urdf.py
│   └── setup.py
└── setup.py
```

Where **init**.py has the following:

```py
from parse import SDF, homogeneous2translation_quaternion, homogeneous2pose_msg, sdf2tfname
from naming import *
from conversions import *
```

This is my setup script

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
  name = 'pysdf',
  version = '1.0',
  description = 'Sdf to urdf converter',
  author = 'me',
  author_email = 'myemail@mail',
  packages = find_packages(),
  scripts = ['pysdf/scripts/sdf2urdf.py']
)
```

The pysdf module has been successfully installed using `python setup.py install` but when I try to run sdf2urdf.py `sdf2urdf.py` it gives me the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sdf2urdf.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('pysdf==1.0', 'sdf2urdf.py')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1429, in run_script
    .format(**locals()),
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/sdf2urdf.py' not found in metadata at '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysdf-1.0.egg-info'
```

Comment: move scripts into pysdf, delete one of the setup.py and addd an __init__.py file to scripts

Comment: I did what you said but it gave me the same error. I editted the question with the new tree project tree and setup.py. The __init__.py insde scripts is empty.